# Socket server not responding when in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, qgis

I'm trying to set up a simple socket server in a qgis plugin. The ultimate goal is to communicate between qgis and matlab.

I found a clear example for something comparable from here:
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/06/27/wxpython-how-to-communicate-with-your-gui-via-sockets/

When implemented it seems to hang at self.socket.accept() even when a client connects with it. The connection is established (tried with matlab and python) but I don't receive anything.
Netstat shows that there is a server listening at the correct port.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class SocketServerListen(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 22001
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Initializing server")
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((host, port))
        self.socket.listen(5)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Waiting for connection")
                conn, address = self.socket.accept()
                ready = select.select([conn,],[], [],2)
                if ready[0]:
                    conn.sendall("hello")
                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Connected to client")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    #receive header and message
                    message = conn.recv(512)
                    #disconnect connection
                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Message:" + message)
                    self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                    conn.close()
                    self.socket.close()
                    break
            except socket.error, msg:
                print "Socket error! %s" % msg
                break
```

In the log I can see the "Waiting for connection" message but it never passes "Connected to client".
I tried implementing it without threading (remove threading, setDaemon and start()->run())and it does actually work then. However the gui obviously freezes then so that's not an option.

Edit:

I removed the select, which was indeed stalling the process, and only close the client socket.
Here's the standalone code for the server:

```
import threading
import socket
import time
import select

class SocketServerListen(threading.Thread):#threading.Thread
    def __init__(self):
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 22001
        print("Initializing server")
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((host, port))
        self.socket.listen(5)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print("Waiting for connection")
                conn, address = self.socket.accept()

                conn.sendall("hello")
                print("Connected to client")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                #receive message
                message = conn.recv(512)
                print(message)
                #disconnect connection
                conn.close()
                #self.socket.close()
                #break
            except socket.error, msg:
                print("Socket error! %s"),msg
                break

listenIncoming = SocketServerListen()
for i in range(0,10):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("doing other stuff")
print("end")
```

And client:

```
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 22001
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((host,port))
message = client.recv(512)
print("Message:" + message)
client.sendall("hiya")
client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
client.close()
```

Standalone this now does what I wanted it to do :). Unfortunately after implementing the changes in the qgis plugin the same problem still occurs. I suppose the problem lies with qgis then and how it handles separate threads.

Comment: Try making an example program that works in isolation, that we can run on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was QGis, or more accurately PyQT which already has some sort of threading [implemented](http://snorf.net/blog/2013/12/07/multithreading-in-qgis-python-plugins/). I can't say I completely understand it but it does the trick:

The worker class:

```
class SocketServerListen(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 22001
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Initializing server")
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((host, port))
        self.socket.listen(5)   

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Waiting for connection")
                conn, address = self.socket.accept()

                QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Connected to client")

                #receive header and message
                time.sleep(1)
                lengthMessage = conn.recv(4)
                message = conn.recv(int(lengthMessage))
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Message:" + message)

                conn.close()

            except socket.error, msg:
                print "Socket error! %s" % msg
                break


    def kill(self):
        self.killed = True 
    finished = pyqtSignal(object)
    error = pyqtSignal(Exception,basestring)
    progress = pyqtSignal(float)
```

Code to run it:

```
def run(self):
    worker = SocketServerListen()
    thread = QThread()
    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    worker.finished.connect(self.workerFinished)
    worker.error.connect(self.workerError)

    thread.started.connect(worker.run)
    thread.start()
    thread.exec_() 
    self.thread = thread
    self.worker = worker
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing here, but my guess is that the client doesn't send anything until your server sends something first. If that's the case then the `select` call will timeout, and you go back to call `accept` *again* which will block forever (or until you connect with another client).

My advice is that you should skip the `select` call.

---

Also, after you close connection to the client you also close the *listening* socket, so no more client can connect.

Comment: Thanks, that solved part of the problem. Another part seems to be qgis.